# SOQL Query Returning Zero Rows on ContentDocumentLink (filtering on LinkedEntityId)

Tags: soql, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

For my specific use case, I need to find all Content Documents on specific object records that meet a
business requirement. However, when I filter by `linkedEntityId` on the `contentDocument` my soql query returns null.

```
// get all confidential opps 
Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOpp = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE 'Confidential%']);
Set<ID> idSet = new Set<ID>();
//store ids in var
// idSet set has 256 opp Id's
idSet = mapOpp.keySet();
// get document info 
List <ContentDocumentLink> docs = [SELECT ContentDocument.title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :idSet];
//returns null (should return many records)
System.debug(docs);
```

I believe the issue is my SOQL query on `contentDocumentLink`. There are plenty of documents that meet this requirement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated SOQL Query**
I also tried the below query (this is on the Account object). Still null

````
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId in (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId = '012A0000001QDQTIA4')```
````

Comment: Try the same SOQL query after enabling the "Query All Files" permission. The "View All Data" permission isn't sufficient when querying `ContentVersion` if the user doesn't have explicit access. I'm aware your question is about `ContentDocumentLink`, but it might be worth a quick check to see if it is a permission issue.

Comment: That still didn't work for me. I tried the following SOQL query as well

Comment: Worth checking that content is enabled in your org and the files in files tab are uploaded as content is also enabled in content settings.